# Pandas, how can I avoid the use of iterrow (how to assign values to a new column in a dataframe based on the values from another dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, iteration, left-join

I have three different entities: **Opportunity**, **Account**, **Activity**.

I need to combine them, in a peculiar way. Let me explain how they are related:

- **Opportunity** N-1 **Account**
- **Account** 1-N **Activity**

Also, it's worth noting that

- **Opportunity** has the following field: `{ opp_id ; opp_date ; acc_id}`
- **Activity** has the following field: `{ act_id ; act_date ; acc_id }`

What I would like to achieve, is to insert into Opportunity the number of Activities which have been done X days before the Opportunity's date.

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
a_new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['acc_id',"opp_id", "opp_date", "act_90", "act_180"])

for index, opp_row in Opportunity.iterrows():
    account = opp_row["acc_id"]
    opportunity = opp_row["opp_id"]
    opp_date = opp_row["opp_date"]
    act_90, act_180 = 0, 0
    for index, act_row in activities_step_7.iterrows():
        if acc == act_row["acc_id"]:
            days = (pd.to_datetime(opp_date) - pd.to_datetime(act_row["act_date"])).days
            if days<=90:
                act_90+=1
            elif days<=180:
                act_180+=1
    events_df = events_df.append({
        "acc_id": account,
        "opp_id":  opportunity,
        "opp_date" : dat,
        "act_90" :  act_90,
        "act_180" : act_180,    
      }, ignore_index=True)
```

Lastly, I do a `merge()` betwenn **Opportunity** and this **new df**. The operation, of course, takes forever. Yet, I have no idea about how to improve this.

The main problem is that I need to insert into Opportunity some statistics which require both data from Opportunity and Activity, but I cannot merge them beforehand because for each opportunity I have more than one activity to consider (and you can't do a left join while you have duplicates)

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

---

***EDIT 1***

**If this is my Opportunity table:**

```
    opp_date    acc_id  opp_id
0   05.08.2019  acc1    opp1
1   25.03.2019  acc2    opp2
2   27.08.2019  acc1    opp3
3   02.09.2019  acc1    opp4
4   22.07.2019  acc3    opp5
```

**and this is my Activity table:**

```
    acc_id  act_date
0   acc1    25.07.2019
1   acc1    26.07.2019
2   acc1    31.07.2019 
3   acc1    28.07.2019
4   acc1    02.09.2019 
5   acc1    02.09.2019 
6   acc1    31.07.2019 
7   acc1    02.09.2019 
8   acc1    24.07.2019 
9   acc1    25.07.2019 
10  acc2    31.03.2019 
11  acc3    31.07.2019 
12  acc2    24.03.2019 
13  acc3    13.05.2019 
14  acc3    05.02.2019
15  acc3    30.05.2016 
16  acc3    30.11.2017 
17  acc3    11.04.2016 
18  acc3    19.01.2018 
19  acc3    19.01.2018 
20  acc2    24.03.2019 
21  acc1    04.08.2019
22  acc1    20.10.2019
```

**then the expected output is:**

```
    opp_date        acc_id  opp_id      act_90  act_180
0   05.08.2019      acc1    opp1        4       4   
1   25.03.2019      acc2    opp2        0       0   
2   27.08.2019      acc1    opp3        7       8   
3   02.09.2019      acc1    opp4        0       0   
4   22.07.2019      acc3    opp5        2       2
```

Comment: Can you add some dummy data and the output you get with it? I believe there are some typos in your code too (last couple of lines: `accout`, `opportuntiy`).

Comment: Done, it wasn't easy, but done ;) and thanks for showing me the typos!

Comment: In your expected output, why does the second row have 0's? There are two actions done from acc2 one day before that date.

Comment: One action is after the opportunity date, while the second returns 0 as days, probably because of some approximations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some `pandas` built-in functions instead of your for loop. This result is a bit different than the "expected output" you posted in your question, but I think it fits your description.

Let's call your first dataframe `df1` and your second one `df2`. 
We can count how many activities fit your condition by writing it out as a function and `apply`-ing it, instead of iterating on rows:

```
def count_activities(row, act_df, days):
    return (act_df['act_date'].between(row['opp_date'] -pd.Timedelta(days=days), row['opp_date']) 
            & (act_df['acc_id']==row['acc_id'])).sum()
```

Since we do the counting in that function above, joining is not a problem:

```
def add_count_activities_column(opp_df, act_df, days):
    return opp_df.join(opp_df.apply(lambda row: count_activities(row,act_df,days), axis=1).rename('act_{}'.format(days)))
```

And the result:

```
df3 = add_count_activities_column(df1, df2, 90)
df3 = add_count_activities_column(df3, df2, 180)
```

my `df3` is

```
    opp_date    acc_id  opp_id  act_90  act_180
0   2019-05-08  acc1    opp1    4   4
1   2019-03-25  acc2    opp2    2   2
2   2019-08-27  acc1    opp3    7   8
3   2019-02-09  acc1    opp4    3   3
4   2019-07-22  acc3    opp5    2   2
```

p.s. - I'd use `opp_id` as an index, with `df1.set_index('opp_id', inplace=True)`.

Comment: This is at least 50 times faster, and no, I don't want to check the exact ratio. Thanks a lot! Any suggestion about how to improve the title, so other users can find this question?

Comment: something along the lines of "how to assign values to a new column in a dataframe based on the values from another dataframe"?